# Stop Calendar from alerting me of reoccurring task?

Tags: ical, calendar, email

I have a meeting every day at 10 am.  At some point I clicked a link to add a reoccurring task to my calendar.
Now every single day 10 minutes prior, Mail opens and I see an alert about the meeting.

This is annoying for 2 reasons.  First, I always know the meeting is happening.  Second, I am not using Mail for my email client, which means it then tries to make me run through the New Account setup every day.

How can I remove this task from my Calendar?  All I can find is a way to Decline a specific day, but not delete the reoccurring task.

Comment: Which calendar client are you using? iCal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the task doesn't prompt you to delete all the other events?

---

Can't you just remove the mail reminder? Set it from Email to None.

[image]

iCal should then just prompt you if you want to update all the recurring tasks.